# The PHP header() function is not redirecting

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

I am using the following PHP code to check a session. But if the session is not logged into then the page is not redirected and just shows the black page.

My *if* condition is right! It is hitting the header function...

Here is my code:

```
if(
    !isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'])
    || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')
    AND !isset($fb_login)
) {
    header("location:login.php?msg=Please+Login+Again.");
}
```

How can I fix it?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2012 10:57:14 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: You might find this helpful: [will PHP header() & exit() securely terminate a script before redirecting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844759/will-php-header-exit-securely-terminate-a-script-before-redirecting) but your question contains too little information to actually say what is the concrete problem you have.

Comment: You might find this more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487156/php-redirect-to-not-working/7487537#7487537

Comment: Turn error reporting on. I would be *very* surprised if you do not get a "Headers already sent" error.

Comment: Error reporting is on ! No errors ... IF condition is perfect. it is hitting header function

Comment: @SandeepKamble: If you are unsure what the cause is despite error reporting, and you're not that fluent with the `header` call, try to use the [`http_redirect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php) function, it needs a specific PHP extension, just saying. It has been made exactly for such cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: @mario I am not modifying the headers. Its perfect syntax ! :( Don't know where it is wrong !

Comment: Well, if you did make everything correctly and in perfect syntax, why bother us with this question?

Comment: Yeah ! Every thing is perfect ! Can you come Gmail IM, i will show you URL ! If you don't mind

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're using `header("Location: ");` after you've output content make sure you've put `ob_start();` earlier in the script. `ob_start();` buffers your script, so nothing is output until you either call `ob_end();` or the end of the file is reached. Calling `header("Location: ");` after content has already been output to the browser can cause problems.

Comment: Your right ! Okay let me try to place Ob_start(); and ob_end(); properly

Comment: No Sorry mate not working :/ same problem...

Comment: So what's happening? You're being sent to a random page or the page is continuing to load? Try:

`if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '') && !isset($fb_login)) {
    header("location:login.php?msg=Please+Login+Again.");
} else {
    print("In else.");
}`

Then if you see "In else." you know that the conditional statement is resolving to false.

Comment: So it's not outputting "In else."? So it must be evaluating to true. But then.. all you see is a white page and you're still on the same page? What happens if you try printing something after `header("Location: ");`?

Answer (score 8):

Put **ob_start();** in the beginning of PHP file. It will help.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    /*
    Your code
    */
 ?>
```

Comment: No use , i have added this code already ! but still not redirecting

Comment: thanks it works for me

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to put an exit; or die; after the command: and make the "Location" start with uppercase

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '') AND !isset($fb_login)) {           
    header("Location:login.php?msg=Please+Login+Again.");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I have tried but no success !

Answer (score 2):

Make the `L` in "Location" capital.

```
 header("Location: login.php?msg=Please+Login+Again.");
 exit(); // Just a precaution
```

Comment: I have tried ! Not working  if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '') AND !isset($fb_login))
  {
   header("Location:login.php?msg=Please+Login+Again.");
   exit();
  }   </pre>

Comment: HTTP header names are case insensitive. There are a couple of problems with the syntax of that header, but case is not one of them. And any sensible user agent will be able to cope with all of them. This is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try formatting the header correctly:

```
header("Location: login.php?msg=Please+Login+Again.");
```

And of course make sure that you are not sending any output (either on purpose or by mistake) before the call.

Comment: I have tried this one . But not working .. same error

Comment: How much of this is *required*? Only the case sensitive "Location" and not the space after the comma?

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Location: login.php?msg=Please+Login+Again.");
exit();
```

Comment: <pre> if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '') AND !isset($fb_login))
  {
   header("Location:login.php?msg=Please+Login+Again.");
   exit();
  }   </pre> Not working

Comment: Not working? what error you are getting?

Comment: No error , its Just show the Blank Page ! It don't redirect

Comment: What is the url of the blank page?

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure that you do not send anything before the header() function
2. Change "location" to "Location: "

Comment: yes i am not sending any thing ! its Top code of the my page. i done correct formatting still it is not working. only bank page is showing.

Comment: Can you make sure that your IF clause is correct and runs header() ? do some echo "something" to be sure

Comment: If is working perfect ! If i set session then my page is loading perfect !

Comment: If the My session is not set then it must redirect to index.php or login.php .. But it just display the blank page

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `AND` for `&&`

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '') && !isset($fb_login)
    ) {
        header("location:login.php?msg=Please+Login+Again.");
    }
```

Comment: My condition is correct , it is hitting header function