# PHP header() not redirecting

Tags: php

My PHP code is inside an HTML file along with the below code. I don't know why the PHP header() is not redirecting. FireFox says "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

**UPDATE** I added the entire HTML code that I'm trying to redirect.

```
    <?php
    function http_protocol() {
        return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://';
    }

    function http_host() {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    }

    function http_uri() {
        return parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
    }

    function http_refactored_query_strings() {
        $queries = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        $refactoredQueries = [];

        foreach( $queries as $query ) {
            $refactoredQueries[] = filter_var(explode('=', $query)[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }

        $queries = implode('/', $refactoredQueries);

        return $queries ?: '';
    }

    function http_refactored_url() {
        return http_protocol() . http_host() . http_uri() . http_refactored_query_strings();
    }

    header ('Location ' . http_refactored_url());exit;
?>
<?php
class Pagination {
public $current_page;
public $per_page;
public $total_count;
public $pages_articles;

public function __construct($page=1, $per_page=20, $total_count=0) {
$this->current_page = (int)$page;
$this->per_page = (int)$per_page;
$this->total_count = (int)$total_count;
$this->pages_articles=array(
'<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/CmU3tnl.jpg"></div>',
'<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/TDdxS9H.png"></div>',
'<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/39rpmwB.jpg"></div>',
'<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/1lBZQ1B.png"></div>',
'<div class="article-loop"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Y5Ld4Qfh.jpg"></div>',
'<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8HumESY.jpg"></div>',
'<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/CqCZBvk.png"></div>',
'<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/q3I72Ul.png"></div>',
'<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/YrzP9A3.jpg"></div>',
'<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/xWmaeb6.png"></div>',
'<div class="article-loop"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/GpGBVZW.png"></div>',
'<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wQVPRVp.png"></div>');
$this->total_count = sizeof($this->pages_articles);
}

public function offset() {
    return ($this->current_page - 1) * $this->per_page;
 }
public function total_pages() {
    //$this->total_count=sizeof($this->pages_articles);
    return ceil($this->total_count/$this->per_page);
 }
public function previous_page() {
    return $this->current_page - 1;
 } 
public function next_page() {
    return $this->current_page + 1;
 }
public function has_previous_page() {
    return $this->previous_page() >= 1 ? true : false;
 }
public function has_next_page() {
    return $this->next_page() <= $this->total_pages() ? true : false;
 }
}
$page = !empty($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$per_page = 3;
//$total_count=8;
$pagination = new Pagination($page, $per_page, $total_count);
?>

<html>
<body>
<div>
<?php
  $i = $pagination->offset()  ;
        $limit = $pagination->per_page;
        while($i<$pagination->total_count && $limit>0) {
            echo $pagination->pages_articles[$i]."<br>";
            $i++;
            $limit--;
        }
?>
</div>
<ul>
<?php
    if($pagination->has_previous_page()) {
        echo '<li style="display:inline"><a href="?page='.$pagination->previous_page().'">&laquo;</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li style="display:inline" class="disabled"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>';
    }
    for($i=1; $i<=$pagination->total_pages(); $i++) {
        echo '<a href="?page='.$i.'"><li style="display:inline; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px">'.$i.'</li></a>';
    }
    if($pagination->has_next_page()) {
        echo '<li style="display:inline"><a href="?page='.$pagination->next_page().'">&raquo;</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li style="display:inline" class="disabled"><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>';
    }
?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo http_refactored_url();` is it correct

Comment: Depending on where in your HTML this php script is the problem may be that header will not redirect after any html has been sent to serve the request. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817846/header-is-not-redirecting-php)

Comment: @rtfm yes, if I do echo http_refactored_url(); that works correctly.

Comment: **The page isn’t redirecting properly** is usully a loop - your not redirecting to the page your on which does the same again?

Comment: Could you maybe run into a redirect recursion? Maybe you should check if your current URL matches the refactored_url before you do the redirect

Comment: Firefox usually stops redirect recursions pretty quickly by itself, I really think you should consider the post I linked above.

Comment: I removed the semicolon after location and now it's throwing a 404. header ('Location ' . http_refactored_url());exit;

Comment: Updated OP with entire HTML code.

Comment: You are redirecting and exiting on every page load so no wonder you are seeing this problem... Your script will never get past the exit();

Comment: even when I place that if-else condition it still doesn't display the images on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that in your URL, you don't have any `$_GET` parameters. In this case, when you loop through `$refactoredQueries[] = filter_var(explode('=', $query)[1]`, you'll have an exception thrown:

> Undefined offset: 1

If you **have** `$_GET` parameters, the page will redirect correctly.

To correct this, you'll want to check that the query exists before attempting to access it:

```
if ($query) {
  $refactoredQueries[] = filter_var(explode('=', $query)[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}
```

The redirect isn't happening correctly, because it gets stuck in an infinite loop when there are no query strings. To correct this, simply check for the existence of the query strings when attempting to redirect. If there aren't any query strings, you'll end up on the same page that you're current on, so you can simply `exit`:

```
function http_refactored_url() {
  if (http_refactored_query_strings()) {
    return http_protocol() . http_host() . http_uri() . http_refactored_query_strings();
  }
  else {
    exit;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Updated OP with entire HTML code. Please check OP again.

Comment: Updated my answer, and it should now correct the redirect behaviour based on the existence of query strings.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It's not outputting the images on the screen.

Comment: It looks like your running exit() on every page load before the image output so how could they ever display?

Comment: even when I place that if-else condition it still doesn't display the images on the screen.